# HTML Agility Pack InnerXml does not returns all of the Inner xml elements

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack, c#-6.0

I built myself a WebNovel scraper that downloads them and converts them into ebooks for offline reading. It's mostly complete except for a last point.

Here is a summary of the problem I'm facing :

- An example of page does not give the expected result : http://beyondtheimpossible.org/comic/fury/
- And another one that works pretty well : 
  http://www.wuxiaworld.com/tdg-index/tdg-chapter-13/

You'll notice that in the former, there is formatting in the text. And it is essential to understand correctly what's going on.

Here is the method I'm using to scrape the webpages :

```
protected override void ScrapeWebPage(WebComicEntry entry, Document ebook, string nextPageUrl = null)
{
    // http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples

    do
    {
        string content = string.Empty;
        string title;
        try
        {
            using (var wc = new WebClient())
            {
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream(wc.DownloadData(nextPageUrl ?? entry.BaseAddress)))
                {
                    HtmlDocument hDoc = new HtmlDocument();
                    hDoc.Load(ms, true);
                    XPathNavigator xNav = hDoc.CreateNavigator();
                    try
                    {
                        title = xNav.SelectSingleNode(entry.ChapterTitleSelector).Value;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        ConsoleDisplay.AddAdditionalMessageDisplay(
                            entry,
                            $"Title not found for page {_pageCounter}, replacing with default value");
                        title = WebUtility.HtmlEncode($"Chapter - {_pageCounter}");
                    }

                    content += $"<h1>{title}</h1>";
                    XPathNodeIterator xIter = xNav.Select(entry.ChapterContentSelector);
                    while (xIter.MoveNext())
                    {
                        //My problem is here !
                        var temp = $"<{xIter.Current.Name}>{xIter.Current.Value}</{xIter.Current.Name}>"; 
                        content += temp;
                    }

                    nextPageUrl = xNav.SelectSingleNode(entry.NextButtonSelector)?.Value;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            if (((HttpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                return;
            }
                continue;
        }

        AddPage(ebook, content, title);
    }
    while (!nextPageUrl.IsEmpty());
}
```

`ConsoleDisplay` is a custom static class that I built to be able to botain a coherent output wehn processing multiple WebNovels in parallel, if needed, it can be replaced with a `Console.WriteLine`.

`HtmlDocument` comes from the [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack)

`WebComicEntry` is a custom class holding the necessary information for the scraping :

```
public class WebComicEntry
{
    public String Parser = "XPath";
    public String BaseAddress = "";
    public String NextButtonSelector = "";
    public String ChapterTitleSelector = "";
    public String ChapterContentSelector = "";
    public String Author;
    public DateTime Date = DateTime.Now;
    public String Title;
    public String Description;
}
```

And Finally `Document` is an Epub document coming from the library [DotNetEpub](https://github.com/gonzoua/DotNetEpub)

What's happening with this code is that I can obtain a proper text (100% readable) but without any style.

The selectors that I am using for the failing example :

- NextButtonSelector : `//@href[@class='comic-nav-base comic-nav-next']`
- ChapterTitleSelector : `//*[@class='post-title']`
- ChapterContentSelector : `//*[@class='entry']`

When I replace `xIter.Current.Value` by `xIter.Current.InnerXml` I get some formatting, but the HTML entities are visible (and since I don't know them all, it's a lot less readable)

What am I missing to be able to obtain BOTH a proper formatting and proper text ? 
(assuming that the formatting is in the HTML and not in a separate css file, I might choose the cover that case later)

If you wish to clone & test the repository is available here : https://github.com/sidewinder94/WebComicDownloader